# How can I correctly convert these to c#, marshall so I can pass these struct to DLL (c++)?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

C++

```
#define FIELD_SIZE_MSGID       24
#define FIELD_SIZE_TIME        12
#define FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN      256


typedef struct

{

      char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];

      char SendTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];

      char ReceiptTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1]; 

} AdminDataM0;





typedef struct

{

      int Type;

      union

      { 
         AdminDataM0 M0;
         char Data[FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN + 1];     

      } AdData;


      char Unknown[FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN + 1];


} AdminData;
```

C#:

```
    [DllImport("Receiver.dll",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
        ExactSpelling = false, 
        SetLastError = false, 
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
        EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    protected static extern int SendMessage(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref AdminData ptrAdminData,
);


   protected const Int32 FIELD_SIZE_MSGID = 24;
   protected const Int32 FIELD_SIZE_TIME = 12;
   protected const Int32 FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN = 256;

   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    public struct AdminDataM0
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = FIELD_SIZE_MSGID + 1)]
        public char[] MsgId;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = FIELD_SIZE_TIME + 1)]
        public char[] SendTime;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = FIELD_SIZE_TIME + 1)]
        public char[] ReceiptTime;
    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
 protected struct AdminData
{
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
     public Int32 nType;

     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
     public Data AdminData_Data;            

     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
     public struct Data
     {
         [FieldOffset(0)]
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
         public AdminDataM0 M0; //135

         [FieldOffset(0)]
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN + 1)]
         public char[] Data_FldSizeAdmin;                
     }

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN + 1)]
     public char[] Unknown;
 }
```

MAIN:

```
AdminData oAdminData = new AdminData(); 
oAdminData.AdminData_Data = new oAdminData.Data();            
oAdminData.AdminData_Data.M0 = new oAdminDataM0();

oAdminData.AdminData_Data.M0.MsgId = new char[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID + 1];                                 
oAdminData.AdminData_Data.M0.SendTime = new char[FIELD_SIZE_TIME + 1];                             
oAdminData.AdminData_Data.M0.ReceiptTime = new char[FIELD_SIZE_TIME + 1];
oAdminData.AdminData_Data.Data_FldSizeAdmin = new char[FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN + 1];
oAdminData.Unknown = new char[FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN + 1];

string M0_MsgId = "MsgId";
string M0_SendTime = "Send Time";
string M0_ReceiptTime = "ReceiptTime";
string unknown =  "Unknown";

M0_MsgId.ToCharArray().CopyTo(oAdminData.AdminData_Data.M0.MsgId, 0);
M0_SendTime.ToCharArray().CopyTo(oAdminData.AdminData_Data.M0.SendTime, 0);                
M0_ReceiptTime.ToCharArray().CopyTo(oAdminData.AdminData_Data.M0.ReceiptTime, 0);


// function to DLL

SendMessage(ref oAdminData);
```

Problem:

Only the MsgId and the DataData_FldSizeAdmin have values which is the same value.
I think it's because they are sharing the same memory address.

UNKNOWN, SENDTIME and RECEIPTIME don't have values.

Comment: I've tried these in c# but i believe that there's still missing... I used [FieldOffset(0)] for both member variables of inner struct since it is a union in c++.

Comment: What platform is this on? Are you saving and loading the data on the same platform? You have to be careful to look out for different alignments on different platforms.

Comment: Thanks Steve! yup! i'm running this on WinXP.

Comment: Steve what do you mean by Alignments? Sorry I am still a newbie in c#.

Comment: When a C# struct is marshalled, it generates a block of bytes. The position of each member of the C# struct within the byte array can vary on different platforms, so you sometimes need to adjust the way marshalling produces the byte array to make it work the same on both platforms.

Comment: Hi fretje, thanks for your advice. but please forgive my ignorance... can you please elaborate (if it's ok) why should i use string instead of char[]?

Comment: Steve: yeah i have read about that, data types differ in bytes in different kind of platform. Ok i'll check the alignments again between the c++ and c# declarations.

Comment: @fretje: I got it! I believe that I have to take your advice. Ok i'll change my structures to use ByValStr.
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = FIELD_SIZE_MSGID + 1)]
public string MsgId;

Thank you so much fretje! really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @fretje: woooowwwww!!! superb!!!! my problem is OK now!!!! i just changed all the char[] to string and everything is ok! display all the values of the member variables.   thanks a lot!!!  :)

Comment: @Steve: thanks also for your explanation about the alignments in different kind of platform. i will sure take note of that.  thanks Steve! :)

Comment: but i need also to figure out why the values did not display when I used char[]... got a new homework. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stead of `MarshalAs[UnmanagedType.ByValArray]`, you should use `MashalAs[UnmanagedType.ByValTStr]` inside the declaration of your struct:

as in:

```
...
public struct AdminDataM0
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = FIELD_SIZE_MSGID + 1)]
    public string MsgId;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = FIELD_SIZE_TIME + 1)]
    public string SendTime;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = FIELD_SIZE_TIME + 1)]
    public string ReceiptTime;
}
...
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype%28VS.90%29.aspx):

> **ByValTStr**: Used for in-line,
>   fixed-length character arrays that
>   appear within a structure. The
>   character type used with ByValTStr is
>   determined by the
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet
>   argument of the
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute
>   applied to the containing structure.
>   Always use the
>   MarshalAsAttribute.SizeConst field
>   to indicate the size of the array.
>
> .NET Framework ByValTStr types behave
>   like C-style, fixed-size strings
>   inside a structure (for example, char
>   s[5]). The behavior in managed code
>   differs from the Microsoft Visual
>   Basic 6.0 behavior, which is not null
>   terminated (for example, MyString As
>   String * 5).

The documentation for ´ByValArray´ sais (emphasis mine):

> When MarshalAsAttribute.Value is set
>   to ByValArray, the SizeConst must be
>   set to indicate the number of elements
>   in the array. **The ArraySubType field
>   can optionally contain the
>   UnmanagedType of the array elements
>   when it is necessary to differentiate
>   among string types. You can only use
>   this UnmanagedType on an array that
>   appear as fields in a structure.**

So I think for your code to work using `ByValArray`, you should also add a `ArraySubType` of `LPStr` to the `MarshalAs` attribute.

Comment: @Ryan: btw, you can accept an answer here on Stack Overflow... Even voting is possible ;-)